# fatal error: Index out range in numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a collapsible menu using tableview. I am getting an error in func numberOfRowsInSection when `return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count` is called. The thing I don't get is when I select profile(One of the tabs) `return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count` is called and it works perfectly and displays array. But when I select settings or options (the other tabs) I get an error Index out of range. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've tried using different arrays for settings and options tabs but I still get index out of range. Help would much appreciated! thanks in advance

This is where the error occurs

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> (Int) {
    let it = String(describing: items[section])
    var item = items[section]

    guard item.isCollapsible else {
        if (it == "ProfileViewModelAboutItem") {
            return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count
        }
        if (it == "ProfileViewModelsettingsItem") {
          return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count

        }
        if (it == "ProfileViewModelOptionsItem") {
            return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count                
        }
        return item.rowCount
    }
    if item.isCollapsed {
        return 0
    } else {    
        if (it == "ProfileViewModelAboutItem") {
            return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count // This works fine
        }
        if (it == "ProfileViewModelsettingsItem") {
              return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count // This is where error occurs: Index out of range
        }
        if (it == "ProfileViewModelOptionsItem") {
            return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count // Also here, fatal error: Index out of range
        }
        return item.rowCount
    }
}
```

The whole code below to get more of an understanding

```
import Foundation

enum ProfileViewModelItemType {
    case profile
    case settings
    case options
}

protocol ProfileViewModelItem {
    var type: ProfileViewModelItemType { get }
    var sectionTitle: String { get }
    var rowCount:(Int) { get }
    var isCollapsible: Bool { get }
    var isCollapsed: Bool { get set }
}

extension ProfileViewModelItem {
    var rowCount: Int {
        return 1
    }

    var isCollapsible: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class ProfileViewModel: NSObject {
    var items = [ProfileViewModelItem]()
    var sideBars = [sideBar]()
    var reloadSections: ((_ section: Int) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()

            let profile = sideBar(movies: [“Followers”, “Following”, “bye”], count: [“1”,”2”,“3”])
            let profileItems = ProfileViewModelAboutItem(sideBars: [profile])
            self.items.append(profileItems)

            let about = sideBar(movies: ["Delete Account", “test”], count: [“1”,”2”])
            let settingItem = ProfileViewModelsettingsItem(sideBars: [about])
            self.items.append(settingItem)

            let option = sideBar(movies: ["about", "FAQ"], count: [“1”,”2”])
            let optionsItem = ProfileViewModelOptionsItem(sideBars: [option])
            self.items.append(optionsItem)
    }
}

extension ProfileViewModel: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> (Int) {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> (Int) {
        let it = String(describing: items[section])
        var item = items[section]

        guard item.isCollapsible else {
            if (it == "ProfileViewModelAboutItem") {
                return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count
            }
            if (it == "ProfileViewModelsettingsItem") {
                return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count
            }
            if (it == "ProfileViewModelOptionsItem") {
                return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count                
            }
            return item.rowCount
        }
        if item.isCollapsed {
            return 0
        } else {
            if (it == "ProfileViewModelAboutItem") {
                return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count // This works fine
            }
            if (it == "ProfileViewModelsettingsItem") {
                return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count // This is where error occurs: Index out of range
            }   
            if (it == "ProfileViewModelOptionsItem") {
                return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count // Also here, fatal error: Index out of range
            }   
            return item.rowCount
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.section]
        switch item.type {
        case .profile:
            if let item = item as? ProfileViewModelAboutItem, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myProfileCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? myProfileCell {            
               let title = item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row]
                cell.profileLabel.text = title
                return cell
            }   
        case .settings:
            if let item = item as? ProfileViewModelsettingsItem, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: settingsCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? settingsCell {
              let title = item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row]
                cell.settingsLabel.text = title
                return cell
            } 
        case .options:
            if let item = item as? ProfileViewModelOptionsItem, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: optionsCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? optionsCell {            
                let title = item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row]
                cell.optionLabel.text = title        
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

extension ProfileViewModel: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: HeaderView.identifier) as? HeaderView {
            let item = items[section]

            headerView.item = item
            headerView.section = section
            headerView.delegate = self
            return headerView
        }
        return UIView()
    }
}

extension ProfileViewModel: HeaderViewDelegate {
    func toggleSection(header: HeaderView, section: Int) {
        var item = items[section]
        if item.isCollapsible {

            // Toggle collapse
            let collapsed = !item.isCollapsed
            item.isCollapsed = collapsed
            header.setCollapsed(collapsed: collapsed)


            reloadSections?(section)
        }
    }
}

class ProfileViewModelAboutItem: ProfileViewModelItem {

    var type: ProfileViewModelItemType {
        return .profile
    }

    var sectionTitle: String {
        return "My Profile"
    }

    var isCollapsed = true

    var sideBars = [sideBar]()

         var rowCount: Int {
        return self.sideBars.count
    }

    init(sideBars: [sideBar]) {
        self.sideBars = sideBars
    }

}

class ProfileViewModelsettingsItem: ProfileViewModelItem {

    var type: ProfileViewModelItemType {
        return .settings
    }

    var sectionTitle: String {
        return "Settings"
    }

    var isCollapsed = true


   var sideBars = [sideBar]()


    var rowCount: Int {
        return self.sideBars.count
    }

    init(sideBars: [sideBar]) {
        self.sideBars = sideBars
    }

}

    class ProfileViewModelOptionsItem: ProfileViewModelItem {

        var type: ProfileViewModelItemType {
            return .options
        }

        var sectionTitle: String {
            return “Options”
        }

        var isCollapsed = true

        var sideBars = [sideBar]()

        var rowCount: Int {
            return self.sideBars.count
        }

        init(sideBars: [sideBar]) {
            self.sideBars = sideBars
        }    
}
```

sideBar struct

```
struct sideBar {

    var movies: [String]
    var count: [String]
   init(movies: [String], count: [String]){
        self.movies = movies
        self.count = count        
    }
}
```

Comment: Only post the code that explains the issue. This is very much too much. And please remove all those empty lines.

Comment: Everytime I post a question I always get asked to post more code so thats why I posted it like that. I've updated it to be more specific where the error occurs @meaning-matters

Comment: Try placing a break point in the "troublesome" block and see if the array `sideBars` has an index `section`. If not, there is something wrong with your logic that populates and/or accesses `sideBars`

Comment: I added a break point to see if sideBars has an index section but I get error Index out of range again. So it must be something wrong with my logic to sideBars @Malik

Comment: Maybe it's because you posted a ton of code, so it's quite hard to go through it all, but I cannot find the part of your code, where you actually populate `sideBars` with data, could you please include that as well?

Comment: sorry about all the code I just thought it would give people more of an understanding. Anyways I've updated it and added the sideBar struct at the bottom @DávidPásztor

Comment: I populated sideBar in override init() { super.init() method.  let profile = sideBar(movies: [“Followers”, “Following”, “bye”], count: [“1”,”2”,“3”])
            let profileItems = ProfileViewModelAboutItem(settings: [profile])
            self.items.append(profileItems) @DávidPásztor

Comment: The problem is that you never actually append the `sideBars` array of your `ProfileViewModel` class, you only ever mutate the array of the subclasses, but you use the superclass` array as your data source, which is empty. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only populate the `sideBars` array of your subclasses. The `sideBars` array of the `ProfileViewModel` class is never populated with data, since you only ever mutate the array inside the initializer of the subclasses. However, you use `sideBars` of your superclass when populating data, which is an empty array.

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    let profile = sideBar(movies: [“Followers”, “Following”, “bye”], count: [“1”,”2”,“3”])
    let profileItems = ProfileViewModelAboutItem(settings: [profile])
    self.items.append(profileItems)
    self.sideBars.append(profile)    

    let about = sideBar(movies: ["Delete Account", “test”], count: [“1”,”2”])
    let settingItem = ProfileViewModelsettingsItem(sideBars: [about])
    self.items.append(settingItem)
    self.sideBars.append(about)

    let option = sideBar(movies: ["about", "FAQ"], count: [“1”,”2”])
    let optionsItem = ProfileViewModelOptionsItem(sideBars: [option])
    self.items.append(optionsItem)
    self.sideBars.append(option)
}
```

Some general advice: please follow the `Swift` naming convention, which is that you start type names with an uppercase letter, such as `struct SideBar` and use lowercase camelcase naming for variable names, such as `var sideBars = [SideBar]()`. If I were you, I would also restructure my whole model, it seems to be way overcomplicated.

Comment: Really appreciate the reply. I guess I'll have to find another way to preform what I'm trying to achieve. Most of the code is from an example I followed.

Comment: No worries. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: just rereading your comment are you able to suggest a way I could populate the sideBar array of the ProfileViewModel?

Comment: ok so now I no longer get the error in numberOfRowsInSection which is good but now the same error appears in cellForRowAt on the line item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row]

Comment: Use the debugger to check that `movies` actually has elements in it and also check that `movies.count > indexPath.row`.

Comment: Im not totally sure what you mean by checking movies.count > indexPath.row but the movies.count is 2. Sorry for my lack of knowledge I'm fairly new to coding to I'm trying learn on the go. Also just reediting my comment, Im unable to check if movies has elements within cellForRowAt because the index out of range error appears when I try to print a statement

Comment: Instead of this line: `item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row]`, do: `print(movies.count)`, `print(movies)` and `print(indexPath.row)`, this way you cannot get an error.

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to print movies.count or movies because 'Use of unresolved identifier 'movies'. indexPath.row = 0

Comment: If I print self.sideBars.count however it gives me 2

Comment: Print `item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies` and the count of that as well.

Comment: I get fatal error: Index out of range. I'm unable to check

Comment: Then first print `sideBars.count` and `indexPath.section`, maybe even your sideBars array is flawed.

Comment: sideBars.count = 2 and indexPath.section = 1

Comment: Then the line `item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies` cannot give you index out of range exception. Btw you should set up a breakpoint in your code and iterate through it step by step to see what might go wrong.

Comment: ok I've got it working. I removed 'item' so instead of item.sideBars[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row] I used sideBars[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row] and it works! Thank you very much for all the help

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple debug technique will be:

instead of:

```
return self.sideBars[section].movies!.count
```

use:

```
let tempSideBarsCount = self.sideBars.count
```

it will help you to understand if there are misalignments between data and cells.